# How to prevent culling or simply redraw on iTowns globe rotation outside of mouse, touch or key events?

Tags: three.js

I'm attempting to rotate the "globe" in iTowns in real time by adding a frame requester (in three.js this would be the requestAnimationFrame loop).

I am attempting to use iTowns to provide a real time 3D earth map simulation. As part of this I have an interval firing every second and playhead controls to manipulate time. I'm trying to rotate an earth representation along the z-axis because in iTowns that is the polar axis. I need to check the time every frame because I can calculate the earth rotation in radians/sec quite easily and as I manipulate the playhead to speed up time I can get a fluidly rotating earth. Also I'm utilizing the default Ortho layer provided in iTowns to add a geographic layer on top of the blue marble default.

```js
// this.view is an iTowns/src/Core/Prefab/GlobeView
const globeLayer = this.view.getLayerById("globe");
const globe = globeLayer.object3d;

this.view.addFrameRequester(MAIN_LOOP_EVENTS.UPDATE_START, () => {
  globe.rotation.z = ConversionUtils.toRadians(this.globals.getSceneRotation());
});
```

The globe rotates, however I believe iTowns is performing some sort of culling of the map tiles/globe. What happens is at some point as the earth rotation is taking place a portion of the globe no longer renders. If this was related to the Ortho layer I believe the blue marble would still show. We have another version of the application without any iTowns and we can rotate a Three.js SphereGeometry without any culling using the same mechanics; so I am 99% sure it is not an issue with Three.js unless iTowns is doing something I don't see.

How do I prevent the culling, which I see is documented as an optimization? Better yet, how can I tell it to redraw properly?

I've tried the following but to no apparent effect:

1. `this.view.notifyChange(globeLayer, true);`
2. `this.view.notifyChange(undefined, true);`
3. `this.view.notifyChange(this.view.controls.camera, true);`
4. `globe.updateMatrixWorld(true);`

There is "culling" logic in:
- **iTowns/src/Core/Prefab/GlobeLayer.js**
- **iTowns/src/Layer/TiledGeometryLayer.js**

This is invoked from **iTowns/src/Core/MainLoop.js**. Bubbling up to the method `scheduleViewUpdate` which is invoked on **iTowns/src/Core/View.js** notifyChange. 
Further digging leads me to believe **iTowns/src/Controls/GlobeControls.js**, specifically the cameraTarget attribute that I can't manipulate, is either the answer or is related.

I am hoping I am missing something and there is a way to code this up. Alternatively, I realize the suggestion may be fork or PR iTowns.

It is worth noting I do not want to change the camera position, just rotate the globe because there are other objects also moving in the scene i.e. satellites in orbit.